# CAS Database tables empty

Tags: hibernate, cas

I've configured CAS in the way it is described [here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuring)

It's working almost as expected, however I'm a bit confused.
I use a SQLServer DB to store the data, but the tables TICKETGRANTINGTICKET and SERVICETICKET are empty all the time.

Is this a normal behaviour?

The following shows the relevant configuration items.

```
<!-- This is the EntityManagerFactory configuration for Hibernate -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xyz:123/CAS;instance=xyz;user=yyy;password=zzz;domain=UUU"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the point where this has to be changed in order to store TGT into the DB.
The documentation can be found [here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/JpaTicketRegistry)

Unfortunately this seems to fill only the TGT table and not the ST

Update:
The ST is used, but as the ST is valid only for about a second and just for one use the table is (almost)always empty